# Counter-example to intersection of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading Ulrich Gortz's Algebraic geometry and saw the following result:

> If $A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra for a field $K$ we have $$\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{a} = \bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}\subset A \\ \text{prime ideal}}} \mathfrak{p}= \bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{m}\subset A \\ \text{maximal ideal}}}\mathfrak{m}$$

I know the first equality is true for any commutative rings.

My question is: Is it true that if $A$ is NOT a finitely generated $K-$algebra, for a field $K$, then, $$rad\, \mathfrak{a}\not= \bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{m}\subset A \\ \text{maximal ideals}}} \mathfrak{m}$$ If yes, then what is a counter-example?

I feel like this has something to do with violating Hilbert nullstellensatz.

Comment: Please avoid images; they are not searchable, may not display properly in all devices (it is very small in mine, for example), and screen readers usually cannot process them, making your post inaccessible. This is a very small one; you could type it up using MathJax.

Comment: @Arturo sure. I'll keep that in mind from next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=k[t]_{(t)}$. This is a local domain with unique maximal ideal $(t)$, so the intersection of maximal ideals containing $(0)$ is $(t)$, which is not equal to $\sqrt{(0)}=(0)$.

It is not finitely generated as a $k$-algebra: if it were, $k[t]_{(t)}[x]$ would be finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, but $k[t]_{(t)}[x]/(1-tx)\cong k(t)$, which contradicts Zariski's lemma that any quotient of a finitely generated algebra over $k$ by a maximal ideal is a finite extension of $k$.

The sort of ring that makes this second statement true is a *Jacobson ring* - what's going on geometrically is that for such a ring $A$, the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ are dense in every closed subset.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the geometric idea?

Comment: Sure - the intersection of all the prime ideals is the functions that evaluate to zero in the residue field at each point, while the intersection of all the maximal ideals is the functions that evaluate to zero in the residue field at every closed point. When the closed points aren't dense, the functions that evaluate to zero at every closed point don't vanish everywhere.

Comment: So it seems,  anytime you localize at a prime that is not minimal, you get a similar situation.